# ASP table row count not getting incremented

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I have an ASP table, with a dropdownlist and text box in its 1st row. I have a button on click of which a similar row should be added. I have the following function in its button click event.

```
public void addRow()
{
    int flag = Table1.Rows.Count;
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = "ddl" + (flag + 1).ToString();
    TextBox tBox = new TextBox();
    tBox.ID = "txt" + (flag + 1).ToString();
    TableCell tCell1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell tCell2 = new TableCell();
    tCell1.Controls.Add(ddl);
    tCell2.Controls.Add(tBox);
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell1);
    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell2);
    Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
}
```

This code works fine when adding 2nd row. When I click the button again, the value of flag which should have the value of number of rows of the table is not getting incremented. So a new row doesn't get created. Can you please tell me why the value of flag doesn't get incremented ? Or is their an easier way to do this ? Direct answer or link would be helpful.

Mark up code for Table:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="410px">
    <asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1"></asp:DropDownList>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

Comment: @TJMonk15 "You simply do not actually understand what is happening", isn't that why the OP is here looking for help?

Comment: @JonP While it is the reason they are here, it is also the reason we constantly have to answer incredibly basic questions. It is a lack of a very basic understanding of programming, or in this case, OOP or (possibly more importantly) the system they are working with.

Comment: @TJMonk15 I've been working with ASP.NET for a while, and I don't understand why it's doing this, though I might with more detail, such as how the table is created. This question has little to do with basic programming and probably more to do with the ASP.NET page lifecycle, which is not a trivial thing to understand. If you know what the problem is, then please post an answer. Otherwise your comment comes across as condescending and unhelpful.

Comment: @Partha, can you provide how the table is created in your .aspx page and also where is `addRow` called from? Button click event? PageLoad? On Init?

Comment: I just dragged and dropped a table and added the 1st row in source. This function is called on a button click event. I am sorry if its trivial.

Comment: @mason any idea where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Please post your markup, and also any relevant section from your Page_Load method. Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason I have added the code mark up for table. There is nothing in page load for now.

Comment: Is ViewState enabled or disabled on the page?

Comment: @mason It is enabled.

Comment: Try adding controls in Page_Init instead of button click handler. Do they persist from there?

Comment: Called the function in Page_Init. 1st row comes from markup, second from Init. Total 2 rows. Then for a button click, 1 row gets added and same problem persists from next click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning - Big ugly block of text**

I'm going to try and explain why what you're trying to do is not as simple as it sounds (or as simple as I'd like it to be) and hopfully give you an alterantive approach, which while it 
may not be straight forward, it should be "better".

It looks a high level overview of what you are trying to do is the following:

> Give the user the oppotunity to add one or more records to a collection (database) before finalising the save.

It is possible to do this using postback to generate the additional rows/items beofore clicking the final save button. Hover this may not be the easiest, or best, way to do this.

From a technical viewpoint adding dynamic controls has to be handeld in a very specific manner at a specific point in the [ASP.net page lifecylce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Dynamic controls also have to be recreated on **every** post back, so every time a user clicks the "add" button, you will have to re-reate the rows you already have in addition to the new row. This is why you only get the one row in this example. Thats just the adding of the dynaimc controls. Wait till you get to getting data from your dynamic text boxes and drop downs!

From an end users perspective, this approach is also not ideal as every time the user clicks the "add" button the page cycles through the request/response process, which at the minumun cuases a bit of an ugly flash.

**Update**

But how? I hear you ask. Well here it is (I've simplified it to one column for this example):

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
 </asp:Table>

 <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="Button1_Click" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRowCount" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />

 <div>
     <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
 </div>
```

**C#**

```
private int rowCount = 1;
private bool rowNeeded = false;

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //Pre-emptively create additional row on post back.
    //We'll remove it if we don't need it later

    //Controls Have to be added at pre-init to maintain their view state
    //Adding a row in the button click event will result in any data 
    //entered in that row dissapearing from viewstate on next post back
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        //Get number of additional rows from hidden field
        //We're using a hidden form field and Request.Form
        //instead of ViewsState and hdnRowCount.value
        //because ViewState has not been loaded at this stage
        //of the page life cycle
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["hdnRowCount"]))
        {
            rowCount = int.Parse(Request.Form["hdnRowCount"]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            // +2 as there are existing controls with "1", eg txt1
            tb.ID = string.Format("txt{0}",i+2);
            tc.Controls.Add(tb);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        }

    }

    base.OnPreInit(e);
}        


//Add Row Click
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    //Hold number of additional rows in hidne field
    hdnRowCount.Value = (++rowCount).ToString();
    //Let the page know we need to keep the row
    rowNeeded = true;            
}

//An Exmple of how to get your data out
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "";

    //Iterate through the table rows finding the controls
    //Using count -1 as we still have the pre-emptive row
    for(int i = 0; i < Table1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)Table1.Rows[i].FindControl(string.Format("txt{0}",i+1));
        s += "," + tb.Text;
    }

    lblResult.Text = s;
    lblResult.Visible = true;

}

protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    //Get rid of pre-emptive row if we don't need it
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!rowNeeded)
        {
            Table1.Rows.RemoveAt(Table1.Rows.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    base.OnLoadComplete(e);
}
```

**End Update**

So, how would I do it? Client side, is the answer to that question. I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to create a clone of the first row. You then would need to adjust the `id` and `name` attributes of your form fields before appending your new row to the table. You would also need a hidden form field to keep track of the number of hidden rows. When your user finaly hits the "save" button, on the C# side, get the number of additional rows from you hidden field the go old school and use `Request.Form[]` to get the value of each of your added fields.

This, in my opionion, will be a smoother experience for the end user.

Another, somewhat hacky option,if you have a defined maximum number of additional rows. For this have the mamimum rows, with form controls in the table. You can then either use `visible="false"` in the aspx and use post back to change that to `visible="true"` when the user clicks "add". The other option there is to give the row a CSS class that hides the row and then use javascript/jquery to remove the class to make the row visible.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer sir !!. I also started working on jQuery as suggested by you.

Comment: I suddenly got requirement to delete a row dynamically if the user wishes to. For this I created a [Serializable] class with all columns of dgv as its members. In page class created a list of that class and performed the operations on it. I stored that list as ViewState and used it as datasource to the gridview. It seems to work fine too. Thanks for the help once again !!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are not understanding [the ASP.Net Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx) and more importantly how it interacts with [dynamic controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) (your added controls.)

Unfortunately, we can not answer this question without understanding whether the values in these "dynamically" created controls are used server-side or client-side.

I can guess that:

1) If they are for client side consumption/usage, you are doing wrong. If you need more info ask another (more specific) question.

2) If they are for server side consumption/usage, you must only allow one new record per postback, and should include a "Save" button that will save the current "new" row and cause a page refresh that the user can add a new entry to.

3) See rule #0 (Every rule has exceptions. {This rule applies in so far that you understand the problem at hand.})

Monk